# mongodb index works differently

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I do not understand if the index was executed with {createdAt: 1}.

Should {device.objectId: 1} index be run?

Sometimes this happens during many attempts.

I know I need to walk a composite index.

But

Even if you do not have a composite index,

We know that if the key used in the condition is contained in a single index, it searches for the optimal query execution condition.

I want to know what caused it to work.

I wonder why this result came out.

**The currently set index.**

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "1000009494.QuestItemLog"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "createdAt" : 1
        },
        "name" : "createdAt_1",
        "ns" : "1000009494.QuestItemLog",
        "background" : 1
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "updatedAt" : 1
        },
        "name" : "updatedAt_1",
        "ns" : "1000009494.QuestItemLog",
        "background" : 1
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "device.objectId" : 1
        },
        "name" : "device.objectId_1",
        "ns" : "1000009494.QuestItemLog",
        "background" : 1
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "content.objectId" : 1
        },
        "name" : "content.objectId_1",
        "ns" : "1000009494.QuestItemLog",
        "background" : 1
    }
]
```

**The query log in question.**

```
2018-06-12T14:04:58.433+0900 [conn199770] query 1000009494.QuestItemLog query: { query: { $and: [ { device.objectId: "5aecd3610cf237a6838337f9" }, { content.objectId: "58f7521fc8f235c33d505e22" }, { $or: [ { ACL.5aecd3dd0cf2716ac95a6d1d.read: true }, { ACL.role:r_01035284674.read: true }, { ACL.*.read: true }, { ACL: null } ] } ] }, orderby: { createdAt: -1 }, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" } }
 planSummary: IXSCAN { createdAt: 1 } ntoskip:0 nscanned:7913847 nscannedObjects:7913847 keyUpdates:0 numYields:46505 locks(micros) r:173389865 nreturned:0 reslen:20 562751ms
```

**row count**

```
shard01:SECONDARY> db.QuestItemLog.find({"content.objectId":"58f7521fc8f235c33d505e22"}).explain();
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor content.objectId_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 5095,
    "nscannedObjects" : 5095,
    "nscanned" : 5095,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 5095,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 5095,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 1865,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 5236,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "content.objectId" : [
            [
                "58f7521fc8f235c33d505e22",
                "58f7521fc8f235c33d505e22"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "BPP-BAAS-MONGO104:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}

shard01:SECONDARY> db.QuestItemLog.find({"device.objectId":"5aecd3610cf237a6838337f9"}).explain();
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor device.objectId_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 153,
    "nscannedObjects" : 153,
    "nscanned" : 153,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 153,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 153,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 1,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "device.objectId" : [
            [
                "5aecd3610cf237a6838337f9",
                "5aecd3610cf237a6838337f9"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "BPP-BAAS-MONGO104:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. All you are doing is sending queries for singular values in `"device.objectId"` or `"content.objectId"`, and since there is an index for these properties then the appropriate one is indeed being selected as can clearly be seen in the explain output. If what you are asking is "how does the query optimizer work?" then that's far too broad a question. The only clear apparent thing is that both of these fields contain "strings" and not actual `ObjectId` values. This is more likely an error, and certainly wasting space and efficiency.

Comment: device.objectId or content.objectId index should be executed.
I did not understand why the createdAt index was executed, so I posted the question.